# What is the filter normally set to at the first epoch of a CNN

Tags: filter, conv-neural-network

By default, for a simple CNN (first layer shown below), what is the filters normally set to at the first epoch?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CNN's are no different than the other layers in Keras. Like other layers, they are initialized randomly. But there are lots of different types of functions to initialize them. you can initialise a CNN like following syntax

```
model.add(Conv2D(number_of_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer=your_function, data_format='channels_first'))
```

here is some of the function that are built in to Keras to initialize CNNs

```
tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)
tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05, seed=None)
tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)
tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
tf.keras.initializers.Ones()
tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=None)
tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=None)
```

for more info check out https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/